# How to remove static from clothes and self?

Tags: clothing, laundry

I think that because of drying my clothes in dryer, I am recently charged with static.

Just now, I "zapped" my colleague just because I was giving him a coin.

Obviously, I do not want to be this charged. Not only because interpersonal reasons, but also because I work a lot with computers and electronics, so I do not want to harm any appliance I should be working with.

Is there a way to remove static from self?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any static charge gained in the dryer will be lost on the first grounded object you touch.

Your issue is due to subsequent build-up of charge, either from lack of fabric conditioner, which contains anti-static compounds, or you are regenerating more static from your interaction between shoes & carpet.

For the first, use either commercially available anti-static dryer sheets; or even just a tightly screwed-up ball of aluminium foil in with the tumble-drying.

For the second, change your shoes. Leather soles create less static than artificial soles, though some artificial soles produce more than others. You'd have to test your existing shoes empirically to see which are best.

Also bear in mind that the entire effect is hugely influenced by atmospheric humidity, so don't think you've found the perfect solution on a rainy day.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I began to be really charged when I started to wear new shoes. I would never ever guess this connection! Thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

You can always remove static from yourself by simply touching the ground with your hand as this will discharge any charge that is present on your body.
Also, if you're working with computers and electronics, you should have a grounding strap connected to your wrist in order to prevent this build up of charge and protect sensitive components!